# Solution of system of nonlinear equations with trigonometric terms

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

**Issue:**

I am trying to solve the following system of nonlinear equations for the unknown variables: $x$, $z$ and $\beta$. The remaining variables are known values.

$$a=u(s^2+(x\cos\beta\ )^2+(z\sin\beta\ )^2\ ) \tag{eq. 1}\label{eq1}$$
$$b=u(y^2+(x\sin\beta\ )^2+(z\cos\beta\ )^2\ ) \tag{eq. 2}\label{eq2}$$
$$c=y \cdot s+(x^2-z^2\ )\ \ 1/2\ \sin2\beta \tag{eq. 3}\label{eq3}$$

It can be assumed that all variables are real numbers and the following may also be assumed positive: $a$, $b$ and $u$.

*Any guidance on how to best approach this question would be highly appreciated.*

**What I have tried so far:**

I have tried solving it with substitution, simplifying wherever I can, but the equations expand drastically and become too complex to handle for me. An alternate route I tried was using a symbolic solver in python (sympy), but this also struggles with coming up with a solution.

Moreover, I have tried adding eq. 1 & 2 together, which produces the following more "simple" equation utilizing Pythagorean identity, but issues with complex expansion still persists:

$$a+b=u\left(y^2\ +s^2+x^2+z^2\ \right) \tag{eq. 4}\label{eq4}$$

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: My first try, which might fail, would be to try to get **inside the head of the problem composer**, which I refer to as **meta-cheating**.  What is the composer thinking?  What is the educational value of the problem?  Which mathematical theory is the problem supposed to be an application of?  ...see next comment

Comment: To me, the obvious **guess**, which might well lead down a **blind alley** is that for all $~\theta,~$ you have that $~\sin^2(\theta) + \cos^2(\theta) = 1.~$ When I look at the original equations, the obvious way to capitalize on this is to **add** the first two equations together, to see where this leads.  So, this would be my first try.

Comment: A casual glance at the equations seems to indicate that if you follow the lead that I am suggesting, and if you temporarily **pretend** that $~\beta~$ is a constant, and that the variables that you are trying to solve for are $~x^2~$ and $~z^2,~$ rather than $~x~$ and $~z,~$ it looks like the result of my previous comments will be **two linear equations, in the two unknowns,** $~x^2~$ and $~z^2.~$  This suggests, perhaps wrongly, that this is the problem composer's intent.

Comment: Hi, thank you for taking the time to comment my question. This is a problem that has arisen in the field of structural cross-sectional analysis.

I have tried utilizing your proposal in the second post, and I still got stuck, but I added a note about this in the original posting.

The third comment you posted where you assume that $\beta$ can be assumed as a known constant is not valid. This value represents an angle betwen two coordinate frames and it will vary for different cross-sections.

I hope this clarified the post, and I really appreciated you taking the time to comment.

Answer (score 3):

From the third equation:

$$
z^2 = x^2 + \frac{s\,y-c}{\sin\beta\cos\beta}
$$

which replaced in the first and second equation leads to:

$$
a = u\left(s^2+x^2+(s\,y-c)\tan\beta\right),
\quad \quad
b = u\left(x^2+y^2+(s\,y-c)/\tan\beta\right).
$$

Therefore, by subtracting the latter two equations, we get:

$$
a-b=u\left(s^2-y^2+(s\,y-c)\tan\beta-(s\,y-c)/\tan\beta\right)
$$

that is, solving with respect to $\tan\beta$:

$$
\tan\beta = \frac{\left(\frac{a-b}{u}-s^2+y^2\right)\pm\sqrt{\left(\frac{a-b}{u}-s^2+y^2\right)^2+4\left(s\,y-c\right)^2}}{2\left(s\,y-c\right)}.
$$

I'll leave it to you to conclude.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to comment my question. This solves my problem, and I can see the numbers make sense! However, I am struggling to see what simplification can be made in the second step you write while replacing the rewritten expression from the third equation into the first and second equation. If you could elaborate on that step it would be much appreciated.

Comment: All the steps are clear now, please disregard the comment above and thank you once again